# Spring JPA HashSet only return one value

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am working with a web application with Spring, and the example database world of MySQL, I have the table countries and the table languageCountries related one to many, when creating the entities in Java, everything works correctly, but when trying to retrieve a set With languages, only one language returns, even if I have more, something is failing me and I don't know what it is.

Pais Class

```
@Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "country")
    public class Pais implements Serializable{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @Column(name="Code")
      private String codigo;
          
      @Column(name="Name")
      private String nombre;
  
      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "Capital")
      private Ciudad capital;
    
      @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinColumn(name = "Code")    
      private Set<Idioma> idiomas = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Idioma Class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "countrylanguage")
public class Idioma implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="Code")

    private String codigo;
    
    @Column(name="Language")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name="Is_official")
    private String oficial;
    
    @Column(name="Percentage")
    private Float porcentaje;
}
```

[image]

Comment: With `HashSet`, I'd check possible collisions of `equals`/`hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

You have the @OneToMany relation in place, but you also need to add the @ManyToOne relation in the Idioma class. There you also define the column with the foreign key.

Something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 3)
    private String code;

    @Column(length = 52)
    private String name;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", targetEntity = Countrylanguage.class,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Countrylanguage> countrylanguageCountrys;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Countrylanguage {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, length = 3)
    private String code;

    ...

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 30)
    private String language;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private Country country;
}
```

I think with https://bootify.io you can create the JPA classes, you can import your SQL scheme there.